# How can I "bypass" control characters while reading a file?

Tags: c

First time asking a question here, I've been usually finding all my answers without needing to post something but today I'm stuck in my small program (I'm not an programmer so I may be doing if wrong).
Here is the problem : I'm reading a log file while looking for some keywords, fairly simple. Sometimes, the log file contains lines with lots of control characters (that I don't understand and are of no use to me) and causes my program to stop reading like this :

```
 Bla bla bla KEYWORD
 Bla Bla [SUB][EM][ACK] (and a lot more)
 Bla Bla KEYWORD"
```

I read the first keyword but the control characters seem to act be like end of life markers for my loop, hence I never read after that.
Here is what I do :

```
FILE *fpIn = fopen(inFile, "r");
char chaine[100];
char searchKeyword[] = "KEYWORD";

while (!feof(fpIn))
{
    fgets(chaine, 100, fpIn);

    if(strstr(chaine, searchKeyword))
    {
        // do whatever...
    }
}
```

If anyone can give me a hint on how to avoid those characters in a simple way, I would really appreciate it !
Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: Assuming [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), those `"[SUB]"`, `"[EM]"` and `"[ACK]"` would really be the values `0x1a`, `0x19` and `0x06` respectively?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe so, but I don't get any "0x.." when I output the line I just read

Comment: @nGz 0x1A is just a way of writing the number 26 in hexadecimal. The character has the code value 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, the control character 0x1A (Control-Z or SUB) will be treated as an end-of-file indication.

You can avoid that by opening the file in binary mode (using "rb" instead of "r" in the `fopen`, but then you will find that all of your lines have a `\r` (0x0D) at the end. (In text mode, line endings are corrected to a single `\n`.)

Comment: Indeed, I'am using windows. Thanks for the input, I'll try opening in binary mode.

Comment: Note that line-endings in Windows is `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ! It works like a charm now !
You've saved me quite a lot of time :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [SUB] is effectively ascii code 0x1A, it used to be the end of (text) file marker in [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M). For compatibility reasons, it kept this role in MS/DOS, and nobody cares to clean that in recent versions of Windows.

The simplest way to remove this problematic byte is to open the file in binary mode. The `\r` will not be removed from the end of lines (end of lines are marked with `\r\n` on Windows and just `\n` on Linux), but at least 0x1A will not be seen as an end of file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried it and it solved my problems.